# polymer-project material design downloaded file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

Am new in HTML5 + Phonegap.

Currently am working in an android application with material design concept. 
I got the examples from [polymer-project.org](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-spinner) and I have downloaded the html file and used in my application. But its not working. 
When I tried to import the html file to my application like http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-spinner/paper-spinner.html its working perfectly.

The problem of this method is ; its taking so much time for load in my application. Is there any method to overcome this issue? How can i use the downloaded html file in my application?

Please help..

Comment: Ufff... Am also having the same issue... anybody have any solution?

Comment: You might want to check a tutorial I did on this topic: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/use-polymer-apache-cordova/

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Crosswalk- Cordova](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html), this worked for me.